# Convert String to JSon on Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

my question is:

How can i do (if is possible) to convert a string with the following format to a json object:

String: Right(Users(Some((ArrayProfiles(List(Some(Profile(Seq(Some(),Some(),Some())))))))))

Thnks

Comment: Play has JSON support. What options did you try?

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you want to achieve, I think you should A. look at the play json docs http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson, B. rephrase it and describe better what it is you want to do, is it to return that string as json? If so JsString(yourstring), is it to parse it as scala and then produce a string, if so the first problem is that it is not valid Scala...

Answer (score 0):

The best and safest way, is probably going to be to write your own parser. For something with such a regular syntax, parser combinators will be pretty easy: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers

Alternately, you can use scala reflection to invoke the compiler on such a string. But be-careful, here be dragons.

And the best answer is probably, why do you even have such a string? You're better off using a different format for serialization (i.e. converting from objects to json directly)